# Ragged and thin font in all users except my account

Tags: 12.04, fonts

there is no problem in my main user account, but in other is system font very ugly. Ragged and thin. I use default ubuntu - font - family. The same situation is in LightDM.

I tried delete .fontconfig folder, unity --reset, Ubuntu Tweak and nothing helped.

Thanks P.

Screenshot of broken font: http://i.minus.com/ibnxpjNSousCBJ.png

Scrennshot of normal font: http://i.minus.com/iQzXY2eMAiTcY.png

Answer (score 0):

Check Universal access settings. You should keep Text size in normal size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I have Normal text size. But i have uninstalled access applications.

Comment: can please provide any screenshoot of your desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts must be installed in `/usr/share/fonts` (create a subdirectory in the directory to store the .ttf files) to be accessible by all users.

Then rebuild font cache with:

```
fc-cache -fv
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have in /usr/share/fonts/ directory truetype. In this directory create subdirectory? Truetype dir is accesible for all users.

Comment: That's correct, store each group of .ttf in a folder named as font family name in truetype directory.

Comment: Extract all subdirectories in new one?

Comment: No, simply add the missing ones!

Comment: I think, that I haven't problem with new font. I use Ubuntu-font-family a this subdirectory is in truetype dir. Of course, accesible for all users (access to files)

Comment: then try just the rebuilding of font cache.

Comment: Done! fc-cache: succeeded  But nothing changed.

Comment: Please, provide screenshots for your user and for another user to see the difference. Don't use picasa, because image sizes are reduced.

Comment: Ok, screenshots are above our conversation.

Comment: Could you try utilities such as Unsettings or MyUnity and post screenshots of "fonts" sections for both users?

Comment: Of Course, in my account is Sans, but Ubuntu font works normal as well: http://min.us/mSPu5SLVZ and broken: http://minus.com/lU9044XwXv7ao

Comment: I'm sorry, now I have to go home. Tommorow i will be here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with font smoothing or hinting and default font selection.

- ### Install Ubuntu Tweak:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
  ```

And check, in the fonts section in 'Tweaks' or another section, that all the fonts (apart from one which should be set as Sans) are set to Ubuntu, and make sure font smoothing and hinting (Basic) are enabled.

Comment: Hi, Marcappuccino, thanks for answer. I have Ubuntu Tweak too and the font settings is same as in Myunity. I thing, that settings is, how should be.